# Field extension corresponding to a quotient of units of local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers and $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal. Pick a uniformiser $\pi$. The construction using theory of Lubin--Tate formal groups yields an abelian Galois extension $K_\pi$ of $K$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(K_\pi/K)\simeq\mathcal{O}^\times$. Note that it is well-known that $\mathcal{O}^\times\simeq\mu_{q-1}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^a\times\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ where $d=[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]$ and $q$ the number of elements of the residue field of $\mathcal{O}$ and $a$ some integer.

> There should be Galois sub-extensions of $K$ in $K_\pi$ corresponding to each copy of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Is it known what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism you write down involving the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not canonical, so one cannot describe them without fixing additional data.
For $\mathbb{Q}_p$ you have $a=1$ and this tower is the totally ramified (p-)cyclotomic tower.

Comment: And I guess that if you don’t choose $\pi=p$ in this case, you don’t even get the cyclotomic tower.